# Problem Building Android Archive for Publishing in Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

[image: This is my android details]

Am I doing something wrong here, I set it to API 29. But I keep getting an error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could set the Target framework via navigating to Build > General in the Project Options.

[image]

Comment: Any update for this case? Have you solved this issue?